# dynamic javascript data with qtip is overriding all tooltips with same message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, qtip2

I have a loop in which many different unique toolbar (title) messages appear.  This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/tw6mLcL1/) shows the problem I'm having. If you rollover the default textbox that is there you correctly see `title test` which is in:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tips" title='title test'>
        test this
    </td>
    <td>
        adf
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have a loop in which it simulates my production code albeit it is not unique data, but the issue is that it is completely changing all the titles including the existing title for the tooltip (title) on hover to be

```
content: 'This is the message!',
```

I realize that the code in the function `loadQtip()` is not specific enough to only change newly added titles to the newly added rows, but I am not sure how to target the new ones.

Currently as you see I am only targeting `class='tips'`

http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/tw6mLcL1/

New fiddle that is showing OP answer along with data that is very close to my own

http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/Lpuf0x7L/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to pass the cloned `.tips` descendant elements directly to the `loadQtips` function. In doing so, the elements are scoped correctly, and the qTips are only initialized on the new elements.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhbosnqu/)

```
// ...

while (count-- > 0) {
  $cloned = first_row.clone();
  loadQtip($cloned.find('.tips'));
  $cloned.appendTo('#blacklistgrid');
}

// ...

function loadQtip(selector) {
    $(selector).qtip({
      // ...
    });
}

// ...
```

Alternatively, it's worth pointing out that the attribute `data-hasqtip` is added to all element that have tooltips initialized. Therefore you could simply negate all `.tips` elements that have a `data-hasqtip` attribute using the selector `.tips:not([data-hasqtip])`.

However, that doesn't actually work in your case because you are cloning the element that already have that attribute. You could work around that by cloning the elements before they have that attribute.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2cu1mcq2/)

```
function loadQtip(selector) {
    $('.tips:not([data-hasqtip])').qtip({
      // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh , sorry for my delay.    So yes this is very helpful.   however  so my real code ends up not being "cloned"   In a loop ( jquery .each )  I am adding "td" columns like this   strResult += "<td class='tips' style='width: 120px; padding:0;' title='" + checkNull(issues.NewComments) + "'>" + checkNull(issues.NewComments).trunc(11, true) + "</td>";

Comment: I realize that it is mostly irrelant  , just that   <td  class=tips   title = unique new value ...  > ..... </td>

Comment: apologize for not have the real data   i'm not cloning , but instead append the table to a div  , and the each of these td have class of "tips"   i could certainly add things like data-attributes     -   would that be needed?  or would passing in the selector of this  work?

Comment: I did add to the fiddle a call to the   addTooltips();  function , but I do not understand how to use the .insertBefore(this);

Comment: -  I went ahead and created a new question - probably going to be easy for you .  thanks in advance       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498956/need-to-get-qtip-to-display-correct-new-javascript-html-table-data-that-is-dynam

Comment: @BrianThornton You can just call `addTooltips()` after updating the HTML with the `.html()` method - http://jsfiddle.net/xfjeasvk/

Comment: Well wait a minute    I need it to show a unique message     title="+ issues.DEPARTMENT

Comment: -  cool   ,  I noticed that even before the qtip tooltip was working , that the tooltip was only showing the first word on hover , thoughts on that?     issues.DEPARTMENT    that department hover

Comment: Also @Josh Crozier  -   you might as well answer my other question that is essentially the same but different ...    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498956/need-to-get-qtip-to-display-correct-new-javascript-html-table-data-that-is-dynam

Comment: @BrianThornton It looks like you didn't enclose the `title` attribute with quotes. Therefore everything after the first space was truncated. See this fix: http://jsfiddle.net/ytbdhpty/