# Need to get qtip to display correct new javascript html table data that is dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, qtip2

I have a similar question in which I didn't have the right data in a fiddle to show.  What the other question shows is doing a table row clone, but my data is table append to a div

The jQuery `$.each` loop shows where I have a dynamically created the title (tooltip)

This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/Lpuf0x7L/1/

```
$.each(allData, function (index, issues) {

    strResult += "<tr><td class='nameField'> <a href='#'>" + issues.LAST_NAME + " " + issues.FIRST_NAME + " " + issues.INITIALS + "</a></td><td>" + issues.OFFICE + "</td><td>" + issues.TITLE + "</td>";
    strResult += "<td>" + issues.DEPARTMENT + "</td><td class='alias'>" + issues.ALIAS_NAME + "</td>";
    // NEED TO ADD QTIP to the issues.DEPARTMENT title tooltip   //////
     addTooltips();
    /////////
    strResult += "</tr>";
});
strResult += "</table>";


$("#divEmpResult").html(strResult);
```

My old question from a few hours with OP answer should be helpful

[dynamic javascript data with qtip is overriding all tooltips with same message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497097/dynamic-javascript-data-with-qtip-is-overriding-all-tooltips-with-same-message)

I am trying to call this function but i know that I needs to have additional data from qtip appended to it.

OP was doing a `.insertBefore(this)`  but I am not sure how to do that with my table row

```
 $('button').on('click', function() {
$('<div/>', {
class: 'tips',
text: 'Dynamically inserted.'
}).insertBefore(this);

addTooltips();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the second code snippet, the `addTooltips` function was called *after* the dynamic element(s) were inserted into the DOM via the `.insertBefore()` method.

In your first code snippet, you are calling the `addTooltips` function *before* the elements are actually appended, which is why it isn't working as expected:

```
$("#divEmpResult").html(strResult);
addTooltips(); // Call the function *after* the elements exist in the DOM
```

In order to prevent the previous tooltips from being overridden, negate all the elements with `data-hasqtip` attributes. You can also set the tooltip text based on the title attribute, or some pre-defined defaults like in the example below:

```
$('.tips:not([data-hasqtip])').each(function() {
  $(this).qtip({
    content: {
      text: $(this).attr('title') || 'This is the message!'
    },
    hide: {
      fixed: false
    },
    position: {
      corner: {
        target: 'topLeft',
        tooltip: 'bottomRight'
      }
    }
  });
});
```

To address your last issue where the tooltips only included the first word, you need to enclose the `title` attribute value in quotes. Previously, your HTML was being rendered like: `title=some words here`, which resulted in the browser automatically inserting quotes around the first white-space separated word and turning the following words into separate attributes.

[**Working Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ytbdhpty/)

The `title` attribute value needs to be enclosed in quotes:

```
strResult += '<td class="tips" title="' + issues.DEPARTMENT + '">' + issues.DEPARTMENT + '</td><td class="alias">' + issues.ALIAS_NAME + '</td>';
```

To avoid mistakes like this, I would highly suggest using a JS templating engine such as [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).